# Laravel 8 Livewire search filter not working with first where clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I want to have a table which shows all the data per company that has a filter search input, the problem is when I put the first argument `where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)` it bugs out and doesn't make the filter search work.

```
$groups = Group::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
        ->orWhere('code', 'like', $filter)
        ->orWhere('name', 'like', $filter)
        ->orWhere('description', 'like', $filter)
        ->orWhereRaw("(CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END) LIKE '%$filter%'")
        ->orderBy($this->column, $this->order)
        ->paginate($this->size);
```

This is my query for the table.

Comment: That is not true, the raw query is doing something else, and rhis is a comment, realted to your query, it is not out of focus, that is why is a comment and not an answer...

Comment: Then how do you intend to query a boolean within the search input? Without using raw query

Comment: As I said in my previous comments, you handle this in PHP, not in SQL... PHP has to know what to ask to SQL... read my original comment...

Comment: Is there any reference for this, I can't seem to find a reliable source for this like you are implying.

Comment: It is basic Eloquent. You can use `1`, or `true`, it will work ALWAYS. You will have to show me your schema so I can see what value it holds and the name of it (so I understand better)

Comment: the column for my boolean is `$table->boolean('active')->default(1);` the problem I'm facing is when I don't query using raw is that the o nly way I can search for the boolean is by typing `1` and `0` not `Active` and `Inactive`

Comment: and that is totally fine, you have to write PHP code to do this logic and then translate it into Eloquent, as I already said in my first comment... `Active` and `Inactive` is your Frontend value, write PHP code to translate that (it should be validated in your controller...) to `1` or `0`...

Comment: So what is the benefit of me exchanging the `->orWhereRaw("(CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END) LIKE '%$filter%'")` to create a new logic in PHP, will it cause something that will future break the table?

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude but this is the last time I will reply because this is getting really long, hence like a new question. You are not going to break any table nor code, the benefit is, AGAIN, in the first comment of mine, super small code, and you remove business logic from the DB and pass it onto PHP, as PHP/Laravel must handle that, not the DB... that is basic SOLID/coding concerns... Relay all your business logic on PHP and all data on DB, do not mix them as the code is going to be unviable... Look again at my first comment and try to do so, you will see it is more cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want `company_id` filter to apply to all `query` and combine other `orWhere` conditions. The other `orWhere` should be grouped in `query` like this:

```php
$groups = Group::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($filter) {
                return $query->where('code', 'like', $filter)
                    ->orWhere('name', 'like', $filter)
                    ->orWhere('description', 'like', $filter)
                    ->orWhereRaw("(CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END) LIKE '%$filter%'");
            })
            ->orderBy($this->column, $this->order)
            ->paginate($this->size);
```

Answer (score -2):

I have solved the query, by adding another where statement with the other orWhere the syntax is below.

For some reason the syntax above worked for Vue but when I migrated Vue to Livewire

```
$groups = Group::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
        ->where('code', 'like', $filter)
        ->orWhere('name', 'like', $filter)
        ->orWhere('description', 'like', $filter)
        ->orWhereRaw("(CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END) LIKE '%$filter%'")
        ->orderBy($this->column, $this->order)
        ->paginate($this->size);
```

Comment: Mixing multiple `where` and `orWhere` without grouping them like @nay showed in his answer, can produce unintended results.

Comment: May I know how will this produce unintended results? I have not encountered any problems with this query so far.